# How to open an index page into a subdirectory without adding /index.html

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

Simple question, let's pretend I have the following path:

```
http://example.com/subdir/index.html
```

I would like to be able to open that **index.html** page by typing this in the browser:

```
www.example.com/subdir
```

and hit enter to have the browser load its included `index.html` page.

Is that possible?

My goal is to have a few subdirectories with the same root domain (***example.com***) and be able to open the index.html pages of each subdirectory without having to add `/index.html` at the end.

Thanks so much!

Comment: how about "www.example.com/subdir/"?

Comment: i tried but it doesn’t work :(

Comment: try this: http://www.fvimagination.com/testhtml/ the testhtml subdirectory has an index.html page inside, but the browser doesn't find that page. May it be because of my root website which is in WordPress? .htacess issue, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sub folders only put this in main root `.htaccess` file :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/index([\.html]*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

For entire website change it to this :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)index([\.html]*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

So , any request with `index` or `index.html` will be removed .

**Note :** clear your browser cache then test it , if Ok change `302` to `301` to get permanent redirection

Answer (score 0):

If you server is running Apache, just create an `.htaccess` file (if you haven't already) and add this line at the top of the file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Comment: it doesn't work yet, here's my .htaccess file: DirectoryIndex index.html

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress maybe it doesn't work because of WordPress

Comment: @fvimagination Where have you put this htaccess file. In root directory or in subdir ?

Comment: @siddharth root directory. so you mean that i have to create a new .htaccess with DirectoryIndex index.html and upload it in my subdir?

Comment: yes you have to place this htaccess in subdir. Give it a try